# consuming Wcf polling duplex service with non-silverlight client?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, html, wcf

i have been working on a online game of TicTacToe and to achive it i am using WCF polling duplex service.
But after thorough searching for the whole week, i think it is possible for only silverlight clients.

If anyone knows that polling duplex service can be used with non Silverlight client like mvc3,asp.net or likewise javascript and so ,,,, then please give me idea, link or sample code snipet.

Thanks in Advance...

Answer (score 0):

you should build your wcf with a REST endpoint. That could be the way to go to consume with javascript.

You can start learning how to do that here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd315413.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget about very cool and useful (auto json serialization/deserialization, easy debugging) WebMethods/[PageMethods](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/abhikumarvatsa/calling-an-Asp-Net-C-Sharp-method-web-method-using-javascript/)

To use server WebMethods from some external (outside page) wcf service you can add script reference to asmx "JS" endpoint. For ex. "/_vti_bin/PageService.asmx/JS" and you are good to go: 
{WCFNamespace}.{WebMethodName}({arguments}) in javascript. Very handy.

By the way Ascx controls for ex. doesn't allow to use PageMethods! And Sharepoint visual webparts based on ascx.